# Why is $\vec a\downarrow\vec c=\vec a\downarrow(\vec b\downarrow\vec c)$?

Tags: vectors

I know how to draw a driagram to show that it's true, but I can't really explain it mathematically / algebraically. This is about projection vectors, if the notation is unclear.

EDIT:
This is the notation I've learned, but after having read about more standard notation, I see that more people would prefer it this way:

$$Proj_\vec c\vec a=Proj_{proj_\vec c\vec b}\vec a$$

Comment: I've never seen this notation before - does this read "The projection of $a$ onto $c$ is the same as the projection of $a$, onto the projection of $b$ onto $c$"?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: This is not so if $\vec b\perp\vec c$ and not $\vec a\perp\vec c$ (I assume the projection onto $\vec 0$ is undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection can be written as $$\vec a \downarrow \vec c=\frac{\vec c\cdot \vec a}{\vec c \cdot \vec c}\vec c$$
What do you get if you let $\vec c=\vec b \downarrow \vec c$?

Comment: I thought this was how you wrote it: $$\vec a \downarrow \vec c=\frac{\vec c\cdot \vec a}{|\vec c|^2}\vec c$$

Comment: They are the same expression. $$\vec c \cdot \vec c = |\vec c |^{2}$$

Comment: Hmm, okay. But why can I let $\vec c=\vec b\downarrow\vec c$?

Comment: Is it not true that $$\vec a \downarrow (\vec b \downarrow \vec c)=\frac{(\vec b \downarrow \vec c)\cdot \vec a}{(\vec b \downarrow \vec c) \cdot (\vec b \downarrow \vec c)}(\vec b \downarrow \vec c)$$

Comment: Yes, it is, how do I explain that $\vec b\downarrow\vec c=\vec c$? Right now that equivalence is only inferred by assuming  $\vec a\downarrow\vec c=\vec a\downarrow(\vec b\downarrow\vec c)$ is true. But how do I prove that it is true? I have to show that $\vec b\downarrow\vec c=\vec c$ before I can say  that $\vec a\downarrow\vec c=\vec a\downarrow(\vec b\downarrow\vec c)$ is true.

Comment: The two expressions aren't equal, I'm just substituting $(\vec b \downarrow \vec c)$ where we had $\vec c$ before. Once you expand $(\vec b \downarrow \vec c)$ in the expression above everything cancels down.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out on my own anyway. It's because $(\vec b\downarrow\vec c)$ and $\vec c$ are collinear, due to the nature of projection.